# Regex to match line starting with +

Tags: c#, regex

If I have an arbitrary text (SVN diff output in this case), how do I match lines that have a first character of '+' given that + has special meaning in regex's?

Comment: [Escaping special characters in regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!

```
/^(\+)/
```

The \ character escapes the +, removing it's special meaning.